# how to do do some means and other calculations for daily data in SAS EG

Tags: sas

I have the following dataset and what I want to do is listed below:

```
data have;
 infile cards truncover expandtabs;
 input MC $ ET $ Date :date9. Time :time. PMC $ PXMC $ Site $ Dia MV SF;
 format date date8. Time HHMM.;
 cards;
US000409 Meas 12Nov2016 17:26 7101 Et1 1 . 2780462.00000 1
US000409 Meas 12Nov2016 17:33 7101 Et1 1 861.26 2780462.00000 1
US000409 Meas 12Nov2016 17:33 7102 Et1 1 861.6 2780462.00000 1
US01036 Meas 12Nov2016 17:26 7101 Et1 2 . 522860.00000 1
US01036 Meas 13Nov2016 17:33 7202 Et1 2 866.68 522860.00000 1
US01036 Lath 13Nov2016 17:33 7101 Et1 2 867.36 522860.00000 1
US02044 Meas 13Nov2016 17:26 7202 Et1 1 . 569298.00000 1
US02044 Lath 13Nov2016 17:33 7202 Et1 1 865.32 569298.00000 1
US02044 Lath 14Nov2016 17:33 7202 Et1 2 865.68 569298.00000 1
US318 Meas 14Nov2016 17:26 7101 Et2 2 . 2630856.00000 1
US318 Lath 14Nov2016 17:33 7202 Et2 3 863.26 2630856.00000 1
US318 Meas 14Nov2016 17:33 7202 Et2 3 863.94 2630856.00000 1
US000409 Meas 15Nov2016 21:56 7202 Et2 3 860.98 2780462.00000 1
US000409 Lath 15Nov2016 21:56 7203 Et2 4 861.5 2780462.00000 1
US01036 Meas 16Nov2016 21:56 7101 Et2 4 866.64 522860.00000 1
US01036 Meas 16Nov2016 21:56 7202 Et2 4 867.34 522860.00000 1
US02044 Lath 17Nov2016 21:56 7203 Et2 1 865.3 569298.00000 1
US02044 Meas 17Nov2016 21:56 7204 Et2 3 865.68 569298.00000 1
US318 Lath 17Nov2016 21:56 7204 Et2 2 863.24 2630856.00000 1
;
run;
```

I want to compute:

**1. Daily Mean of 'Dia' for each 'MC'**

**2. For each 'PMC', step 1 above**

**3. For each 'MC', what is the difference between 'MV'**

**4. For each Year in 'Date', how many Lath are there for each 'MC'**

I tried one way:

```
PROC MEANS DATA=have ;
  CLASS MC;
  VAR Dia;
  OUTPUT OUT=want1 MEAN= ;
RUN;
```

But looking for other options and ways...

Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

One way to calculate mean DIA by other variables using PROC SQL:

```
proc sql;
select MC
    ,Date
    ,mean(DIA) as meanDIA
from have
group by MC, Date;
quit;
```

Another option:

```
proc means data=have;
class MC Date;
var DIA;
run;
```

Comment: I'm not sure what the best way is to calculate the difference between `MV` for each `MC`, maybe checkout the`RETAIN` statement.

Comment: I just started learning SAS, some 1 month ago. so not sure how `retain` can be helpful. :(